# why my android transition make the screen black?

Tags: android, api, animation, transition, shared

**Video of my problem with the shared transition**

[click to see the video of my problem](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=upeNTU9-6YM)

**This is the operation made by me in the app**

i have a shared view (an ImageView) inside a CardView, when i click on the CardView the OnClick method change the image proprety ImageView.setTransitionName(str) of the ImageView inside the card in base of the position of the CardView inside the RecyclerView. After the method onClick pass the name of the transition at the intent,and create the ActivityOption.
After that the secondary Activity in the onCreate method, recived the name of the transition change the name of the ImageView in the secondary Activity.

Why when i run this code, i see this glitch?

```
private List<ContactInfo> contactList;
private Context context;
private Activity activity;

public ContactAdapterCustom(List<ContactInfo> contactList,Context context,Activity activity) {
    this.contactList = contactList;
    this.context = context;
    this.activity = activity;
}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return contactList.size();
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ContactViewHolder contactViewHolder, int i) {
    ContactInfo ci = contactList.get(i);
    //contactViewHolder.vTitle.setText("reagente");
    //contactViewHolder.vCardView.setBackgroundDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.vetreria));
    //contactViewHolder.vCardView.setBackgroundDrawable();
}

@Override
public ContactViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        final View itemView = LayoutInflater.
                from(viewGroup.getContext()).
                inflate(R.layout.single_element_card_mockup, viewGroup, false);

        final String nome_transizione_condivisa = "immagine_numero_" + String.valueOf(i);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, InfoElementActivity.class);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                ImageView immagine = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.immagine_condivisa);
                immagine.setTransitionName(nome_transizione_condivisa);
                ActivityOptions options = ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(activity,immagine,nome_transizione_condivisa);
                intent.putExtra("EXTRA_IMAGE_TRANSITION_NAME", nome_transizione_condivisa);
                context.startActivity(intent,options.toBundle());
            }
        });

        return new ContactViewHolder(itemView);
}
```

Comment: Did you get the solution for this ?

Comment: nope, i had lost the code. I will never know why it doesn't worked